# Using Joins and subquery Performance

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join

I have a beginner question,  and I need to verify if the query would return the correct results given the following setup.
Table 1: Employee Table: Primary Key – Employee ID

```
e.g.
Employee ID Name
1010        JohnDoe
1020        JaneDoe
1030        JimDoecode here
```

Table 2: Consultant Table – Primary Key- Consultant ID
e.g.

```
Consultant ID   Name
2020        Stack1
2030        Stack2
2040        Stack3
```

Table 3: Users table – Primary ID – Userid, Foreignkeys: Employee ID, Consultant ID
e.g.

```
User ID     EmployeeID  ConsultantID    Status
5020A       1010                Active
5030B       1020                Inactive
5040C       1030                Active
6050A               2020        Inactive
6060B               2030        Active
6070C               2040        Active
```

Account table – Primary ID – Accountid, Foreignkeys: Employee ID, Consultant ID

```
AccountID   EmployeeID  ConsultantID
AABB1       1010
BBCC2       1020
CCDD3       1030
DDEE4               2020
EEFF5               2030
FFGG6               2040
```

If I am an employee and somehow also a consultant and vice versa, I will have an employeeid and consultantID and two userids.

My query would need to return active users from Users table and display AccountID, Userid, Employeeid, Consultantid and Name.

```
Such as:
User ID     AccountId   EmployeeName    ConsultantName
5020A       AABB1       JohnDoe
5040C       CCDD3       JimDoe
6060B       EEFF5                   Stack2
6070C       FFGG6                   Stack3
```

Without having a deep knowledge of the tables, would it be a mistake to make joins such as

```
where users.employeeid=employee.employeeid
and users.consultantid=consultant.consultantid
```

and same for account table?
Is it efficient to join tables this way? Or is it better to make use of subqueries?  I have joined the tables this way and performance is terrible.

Comment: Yes, it is  a mistake to put `join` conditions in the `where` clause.  Always use explicit, proper `join` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say that what you did is a *mistake* - zillions of Oracle queries run that way *for ages* (and will probably continue to do so). Although, I agree - it would be *way better* if you get used to ANSI join syntax as it is easier to read, you'd separate *joins* from *conditions* (placed in the WHERE clause), not to mention an impossible (literally) task to outer join the same table to two (or more) other tables using old Oracle outer join (+) operator.

Optimizer will rewrite your code anyway, only if it concludes that it'll get better performance if it does so.

Now, as of a terrible performance, did you - at least - create indexes on those 4 columns you specified? If not, try to do so and run query again (several times) and compare execution times.

Collect statistics so that (previously mentioned) optimizer would have data necessary to do its job.

Check the execution plan - it might reveal some useful information as well.

Any improvement after you do all of that?